# How to change css in rocket.chat

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker, rocket.chat

I want to change css, Rocket.chat
Installed on (Ubuntu_Docker _ AWS) (/home/ubuntu/Rocket.chat)

I already tried to make changes in packages, Rocket.Chat/packages/rocketchat-theme in all CSS files with filezilla but it does not work any result ??!!

for example i want change blue by red in CSS File
   https://demo.rocket.chat/home

Thanks :)

Comment: You're new so I'll give you some feedback. I'm not sure anyone can help you with the way you're describing your problem. You really need to read the guidelines for asking questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Alkaline thanks 4 your roteur i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to your Rocket.Chat instance's Administration panel, then go to submenu Layout and expand the Colors panel. There are quite a few pre-defined colors you can change:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much but me i want change in CSS file

Comment: Then you should describe exactly what you tried to do and what errors you got. There's no way anyone will be able to help you if you don't provide complete details. Which files have you changed? How are you running the project? What errors show up in console?

Comment: I want to know just where the css file

Comment: rocket.chat uses meteor packages to define ui and themes, then exposes the ability to edit some elements through the administration UI. I believe [rocketchat-theme](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/tree/develop/packages/rocketchat-theme) would be a package that might be relevant -- but editing that means that you need to create a new _build_ of rocket.chat and deploy that build.

Comment: also, in the latest builds there is a "Custom CSS" section in the administration panel under 'Layout' that you can use.